# Convergence or divergence of $a_n=\frac{(n-1)!^2 \cdot x^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

If

$$a_n=\frac{(n-1)!^2 \cdot x^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}$$

where $x>0$

then find convergence or divergence

my attempt:

I applied *d`alemberts ratio test*

i.e

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{n!^2.x^{2}}{(2n)!}.\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!^2}=\frac{n^2.(n-1)!^2}{(2n).(2(n-1))!}.\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!^2}.x^2=\frac{n^2 \cdot x^{2}}{2n}=\frac{n \cdot x^{2}}{2}$$

so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}=\infty$$

diverge for all value of $x>0$.

But actual answer is convergent for

$$x^2<4$$

else diverge.

please point out my mistake

Comment: Find convergence of....?

Comment: I attempted to fix some of your MathJax. Please review my [edit]s to ensure I didn't change anything. (I also did some minor whitespace editing.) Also, not all of your steps seem to make sense. For example, what does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}=\infty$ mean? The limit of "nothing" doesn't make any sense. And how did you come to the conclusion that$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n^2\cdot x^2}{2n}$$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done mistake in $(2n)!=(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)!$, so at $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ comes: $$\frac{(2n-2)!}{2n!}=\frac{1}{(2n)(2n-1)}$$  No other mistake!

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{(n)!^2 \cdot x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!^2 \cdot x^{2n-2}}=\frac{n^2 \cdot x^{2}}{2n(2n-1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\frac{(n!)^2x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}{\frac{((n-1))^2x^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}}\right)\\\\
&=x^2\,\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{(2n)(2n-1)}\right)\\\\
&=(x/2)^2
\end{align}$$

And you can wrap up the rest.